# Solving a quadratic congruence $x^2-2x+4 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics

Solving a quadratic congruence $x^2-2x+4 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$ where $x\in \mathbb{Z}_9$.

**My idea:**

$x^2-2x+4\equiv (x-1)^2+3 \equiv 0 \pmod{9} \iff (x-1)^2=6\pmod{9}$. How can I deal with mod 9 since it's not prime...

Comment: By the linked dupe: $\ 3^2\mid (x\!-\!1)^2-\color{#c00}2(3)\Rightarrow\,3\mid\color{#c00}2\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I claim there is no such $x$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is quite small, you can do brute force: you have only to check that for every $k \in \{0,1,2,..., 8\}$ no one square $k^2$ is congruent to $6$ mod $9$. Thus you cannot find a $x$ that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Considering $\mod 3$, it must be
$$
\Big[(x-1)^2\equiv 0\mod 3\Big]{\iff \Big[x-1\equiv 0\mod 3\Big]
\\\iff \Big[ (x-1)^2\equiv 0\mod 9\Big]
\\\iff \Big[ 6\equiv 0\mod 9\Big]
\\\iff \text{Contradiction}
}
$$
hence, this equation has no integer solution.

Answer (score 0):

It has no solution since $6\equiv -3\bmod 9$   is not a square mod. $9\mkern1mu$:

\begin{array}{r|*{4}{r}}
n&0&\pm 1&\pm 2&\pm 3&\pm4 \\
\hline
n^2&0&1&4&0&-2
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- $(x-1)^2+3=0\iff(x-1)^2=6$. There are not solutions because $(\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z)^2=\{0,1,4,7\}$.